# jquery to asp.net c# generic handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to call a c# generic handler from a jquery.ajax call.

My site structure is:
       a/handlers/dowork.ashx
       calling.aspx

here is the code for the above files:
calling.aspx file
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="calling.aspx.cs" Inherits="myapp.calling" %>

```
//the jsonDataObj looks like: 1,t
function sendData(jsonDataObj) {
var status = "";

jQuery.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '/a/handlers/dowork.ashx/doit',
 data: jsonDataObj,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (output, status, xhr) {
  status = xhr.responseText;
  statusCode = xhr.status;
  console.log(status + "  " + statusCode);
 },
 error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  status = "{'d':'0," + errorThrown + "'}";
  status = status.replace(/'/g, '"');
  statusCode = xhr.status;
  console.log(status + "  " + statusCode);
 }
});
}
```

dowork.ashx.cs -- generic handler

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Services;
 using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Xml;
 using Elmah; 

namespace myapp
{
public class dowork : System.Web.UI.Page, IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
}
public bool IsReusable
{
 get { return false; }
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string doit(object data)
{
 string status = string.Empty;
 string number = string.Empty;
 string letter = string.Empty;
 dynamic strings = ((IEnumerable)data).Cast<object>().Select(x => x == null ? x : x.ToString()).ToArray();

 number = strings(0).ToString();
 letter = strings(1).ToString();

 status = number + letter;
 return status;
}
}
}
```

My Error is as follows:

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
 Parser Error
 Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to    service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'myapp.a.handlers.dowork'.
Source Error:
Line 1: <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="dowork.ashx.cs" Class="myapp.a.handlers.dowork" %>
Source File: /a/handlers/dowork.ashx Line: 1
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET  Version:4.6.1038.0
```

I can't seem to figure this one out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From this line of error i am seeing that

```
Line 1: <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="dowork.ashx.cs" Class="myapp.a.handlers.dowork" %>
```

the fully qualified class name is `myapp.a.handlers.dowork`

but in your `dowork.ashx.cs` file the fully qualified class name will be `myapp.dowork`

So give a try giving the proper class name in `dowork.ashx.cs` file.

it should solve the issue

Comment: i did this: <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="dowork.ashx.cs" Class="myapp.dowork" %>  and it's better but now i get an odd error:  An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @will2m  I think `dynamic strings` causing the issue.Can you change it to actual data type. By the way this a different issue altogether. You can this in a different post